# The Borg against d4?

Tags: opening, 1.d4

Until recently, I played the London System, which served be well and was very solid, but every game I played was very similar and dull.

However, I have now started playing "Grob's Attack" as white, which is 1. g4 as well as "The Borg" as black which goes 1. e4 g5. I have found that these openings are a lot more interesting and my chess games are more fun.

However, now I do not have a response against 1. d4. My question is, if 1. ... g5 is a valid response after 2. bxg5. Keeping in mind I play chess for fun at about the 1500 level, does this line hold any possibilities for black? And if not, do you have any recommendations for an unorthodox aggressive opening against d4?

Comment: If you want to play the Borg against 1.d4 play 1...h6 first then 2...g5.

Comment: Related question: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/looking-for-aggressive-opening-for-black-vs-1d4?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The position after 1. d4 g5 is close to the worst Black can possibly have after the first move. If you really want to give up a pawn on the first move, the Englund Gambit (1. d4 e5) is better, relatively, without being popular.

Answer (score 2):

Accepting the Grob gambit, after 1.g4 d5 2.Bg2 Bxg4 is considered risky, because 3.c4 puts some pressure on Black and there are a lot of tactical tricks to be aware of. But after 1.d4 g5 2.Bxg5 Black has a minus tempo in comparison to the previous line and the gambit in my view is not justified.

Anyway, why should you give a Pawn right at the first move, when there are plenty of playable defenses for Black vs. 1.d4?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot play the Borg against d4. I believe that you should, if you want something exciting, to play the Benoni defence, Dutch defence, King's Indian defence, or the Albin Counter Gambit(depends on what White plays).